# Can't find a button 'ctl00' with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

From this page:

```
https://permits.losgatosca.gov/CitizenAccess/default.aspx
```

I'm trying to push the **'Search Permits'** button under Building Permits.

This is its xpath:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl"]/span
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
url = "https://permits.losgatosca.gov/CitizenAccess/default.aspx"


driver_1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver_1.get(url)

NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl"]/span'
# "//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl"]/span"
button = driver_1.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
```

But I get this message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl\"]/span"}
>       Stacktrace:

Comment: "This is its xpath". How do you know that is the right xpath?

Comment: `id="span_link_0"` or `#span_link_0`

Comment: This is not it's xpath. Check page source again

Comment: @RemcoW  I'm getting the Xpath with chrome. It could be wrong

Comment: @dot.Py How did you get that id? Still not working.

Comment: @LuisRramirez by using `INSPECT ELEMENT` on the element you wanna get the selector. Then I wrote his `ID` and `UNIQUE SELECTOR`

Comment: It's inside a `frame`.. you need to switch that frame first than go to find element like `driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame")`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur How do I know that it's in a frame? And where do I get the frame id?

Comment: @LuisRramirez `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")` execute this in your browser console and see the result...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame") did work. Thanks I'll check on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a frame with id `ACAFrame`, you need to switch that frame first as below :-

```
driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame")
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_TabDataList_TabsDataList_ctl01_LinksDataList_ctl00_LinkItemUrl"]/span'
button = driver_1.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
```

**Edited..**

After clicking `Search Permits` to perform action on opened form you should try as below :-

```
driver_1.switch_to.default_content()
driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame")
# now find your desire element
```

Hope it will work...:)

Comment: I think I'm having the same error in the windows that loads just after I push the button. I'm trying to write in the "Street Name: " text box.

Got this:

Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//*[@id=\"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_generalSearchForm_txtGSStreetName\"]"}

Comment: Should I ask that in a new question?

Comment: need to switch again that frame first default `driver_1.switch_to.default_content()`  than `driver_1.switch_to_frame("ACAFrame")`